# Dual boot Ubuntu AMD drivers not installed correctly - login screen loop

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics

I just setup Ubuntu 16.something.something and I tried installing the latest AMD drivers [(this one)](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64). I installed them using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=evqpassbyqA). When the installation finishes I get an error pop up saying it didn't install correctly and prompts to check the install log which gives me the following error message:

```
NOTE: If your system has logged the missing packages required for installation, install them in the order as per the log file to resolve package-dependency issues.
Package dh-modaliases is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dh-modaliases.
Package execstack is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install execstack.
Package debhelper is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install debhelper.
Package dkms is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install dkms.
Package lib32gcc1 is missing from the system. Install it using the command apt-get install lib32gcc1.
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.
Unloading radeon module...
rmmod: ERROR: Module radeon is in use
Unloading drm module...
rmmod: ERROR: Module drm is in use by: ttm drm_kms_helper radeon
[Message] Kernel Module : Trying to install a precompiled kernel module.
[Message] Kernel Module : Precompiled kernel module version mismatched.
[Message] Kernel Module : Found kernel module build environment, generating kernel module now.
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf .c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .?? *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-38-generic/build SUBDIRS=/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic'
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘firegl_major_proc_read’:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:634:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     len = seq_printf(m, "%d\n", major);
         ^
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘KCL_fpu_save_init’:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6458:49: error: ‘XSTATE_FP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (!(fpu->state.xsave.header.xfeatures & XSTATE_FP))
                                                 ^
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6458:49: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: At top level:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6448:12: warning: ‘KCL_fpu_save_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int KCL_fpu_save_init(struct task_struct *tsk)
            ^
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o' failed
make[2]: * [/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x' failed
make[1]: * [module/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic'
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'kmod_build' failed
make: * [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to compile kernel module - please consult readme.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

After restarting my pc after I get asked to I try login where I get a login loop. Pretty much I type my password, it displays a blank desktop for a second then reverts back to the login screen. This just repeats itself.
I'm new to Linux and a don't have much knowledge with coding (besides my intermediate knowledge of HTML, CSS, etc.)

My specs are:

```
AMD FX-6300 CPU
ASRock Pro3 R2.0 Mobo
Gigabyte 270x
HyperX ddr3 RAM
Segate HDD - partitioned for Linux and Windows 10 dual boot
```

Please give assistance :)

Comment: If you just install then there's nothing to loose. Install again and this time do NOT try to install AMD proprietary drivers because there aren't any for 16.04. Depending on the hardware your AMD Graphics will be using either *radeon* or *amdgpu* already. That's all.

Comment: So you're saying to fresh install Ubuntu and not bother installing my GPU drivers (just wanna make sure I understand)? If that's the case I need to find a way around it because I want to install Steam and I read somewhere that Steam needs GPU drivers to run

Comment: Exactly. And there's no way around it, regardless of Steam (it should work though).

Comment: I guess I have a new problem then; installing Steam. Thanks for the help anyway. I actually found out after booting again that the broken Ubuntu drivers were interfering with my Win 10, strangely.

Comment: Whatever is on Ubuntu DOES NOT interfere with the other OS.